# Unbound Field in Standalone Projection

Tags: acumatica

I have a Rich Text field attached to the PMQuote and CRQuote DACs. On the CRQuote, the user field is on the standalone class and the regular class, and that is working as desired. However, Acumatica's reporting does not show the HTML formatting so I am creating an unbound Plain Text field to put on the reports and in GI's. This field works fine on the PMQuote, but not on the CRQuote. On the CRQuote, the field is there, but it is always blank. I'm sure it is something to do with the projection, but I'm not sure how it should be created.

Here is the PMQuote field (working properly)

```
    [PXString(IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(Visible = false, DisplayName = "Scope Text")]
    public virtual String UsrScopePlainText
    {
        get
        {
            return PX.Data.Search.SearchService.Html2PlainText(UsrScope);

        }
    }
    public abstract class usrScopePlainText : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrScopePlainText> { }
```

And here is what I have on the CRQuote (not working):

```
public class CRQuoteExt : PXCacheExtension<CRQuote>
{
    #region UsrScope
    [PXDBText(IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(CRQuoteStandaloneExt.usrScope))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Scope")]

    public virtual string UsrScope { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrScope : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrScopePlainText
    [PXString(IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(Visible = false, DisplayName = "Scope Text")]
    public virtual String UsrScopePlainText
    {
        get
        {
            return PX.Data.Search.SearchService.Html2PlainText(UsrScope);

        }
    }
    public abstract class usrScopePlainText : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}

public class CRQuoteStandaloneExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.CRQuote>
{
    #region UsrScope
    [PXDBText(IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Scope")]
    public virtual string UsrScope { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrScope : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrScopePlainText
    [PXString(IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(Visible = false, DisplayName = "Scope Text")]
    public virtual String UsrScopePlainText
    {
        get
        {
            return PX.Data.Search.SearchService.Html2PlainText(UsrScope);

        }
    }
    public abstract class usrScopePlainText : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: BqlField property is missing on UsrScopePlainText field

Comment: BqlField is not part of PXString, only PXDBString. Should I change it to PXDBString on the regular class even though it is a non-persisting field?

Comment: As I suspected, you can't make the regular class PXDBString if the Standalone class is PXString. But I can't add a BQLField to point to the standalone class because it is not part of PXString.

Comment: This is correct. I think you should keep the PXDBString custom field on the StandAlone CRQuote DAC(DB table one), and on the CRQuote DAC Extension (not the Standalone one) instead of using a PXDBString on the UsrScope Field use a PXString(Unbound) but use PXDBScalar attribute to get the value from the Standalone version. And make sure that your UsrScopePlainText field [dependsOn...]  usrScope field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened, but I put the original code I posted above back into the customization project and it started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution could be to have a reusable attribute that you can attach to any field. I think this is cleaner than adding logic directly in the Data Access class...

```
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Data;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
  public class InventoryItemPlainTextBodyExt : InventoryItem
  {
    [HtmlToText(typeof(InventoryItem.body))]
    [PXDependsOnFields(typeof(InventoryItem.body))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Body (Plain Text)")]
    public virtual string BodyPlainText { get; set; }
    public abstract class bodyPlainText : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<bodyPlainText> { }
  }
  
  [PXString]    
  public class HtmlToTextAttribute : PXEventSubscriberAttribute, IPXFieldSelectingSubscriber
  {
    protected Type _htmlField;

    public HtmlToTextAttribute(Type htmlField) :base()
    {
      _htmlField = htmlField;
    }
      
    public void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
      e.ReturnValue = PX.Data.Search.SearchService.Html2PlainText(sender.GetValue(e.Row, _htmlField.Name) as string);
    }
  }
}
```